# Как переделать макет сайта?

Tags: html, dle

У меня такого вида сайт

[image: макет]

А я хочу сделать, чтоб публикация и в строку, была и в столбик типа такого

[image: макет]

в DLE. В каких документах или какими скриптами мне так изменить вид макета?

Comment: Переверстать.

Answer (score 1):

Блоки нужно собрать вот так (скопирйте в файл, посмотрите как получится):

```
  <div style="width:300px; background:#EEE;">
  <div style="background:#FF0; width:98px; height:98px; float:left; margin: 0 2px 2px 0;">1</div>
 <div style="background:#FF0; width:98px; height:98px; float:left; margin: 0 2px 2px 0;">2</div>
 <div style="background:#FF0; width:98px; height:98px; float:left; margin: 0 2px 2px 0;">3</div>
 <div style="background:#FF0; width:98px; height:98px; float:left; margin: 0 2px 2px 0;">4</div>
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
 <div>text</div>
```

Comment: Как не красиво... CSS рулят ;)

Answer (score 0):

Можете сделать таблицу! 4 столбца и вниз цикличностью.

Answer (score 0):

В файле каскадных таблиц стилей (CSS).